# Debugging modified Assembly

Tags: .net, mono, mono.cecil

I modified an Assembly using CECIL and saved both Assembly and its pdb back to disk. Now, is there a way to generate code file, i.e. c# file, from this modified Assembly and able to debug to that file during runtime?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate C# file for the modified assembly without having C# file for the original assembly?

Comment: Original source file will be there. But I don't want to disturb original file or original Assembly. Becasue I am implementing some analysis/testing logics inside modified assembly and referring this modified assembly in a new project. From this project we need to  debug the modified assembly, original source and assmebly will be available some where though.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to modify the source code (using something like Roslyn or NRefactory) and then recompile that?

Comment: There's some scope with this approach. But practically, if you are doing some post compile activities like Profiling, Auto Generation of Unit test, Code Analysis etc...people don't want to touch the real code. They are expecting the process to be run in a separate assembly. I am now just looking whether there is any ILSpy API can be used inside CECIL to get the full decompiled source code of an Assembly. It may contain multiple .CS files.

Comment: I don't understand that argument. If you modify the source code, you can still have two assemblies (the original and the modified one). And you do want to touch the "real code", except you're trying to do it in a roundabout way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load it in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). Select the desired assembly from the left-hand panel. Then, select "Save Code" from the File menu. This will export C# source code along with a Visual Studio project that can be opened in Visual Studio for debugging purposes.

Comment: ILSpy UI will do it. Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: Yes. According to [this post](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/12982/35303.aspx#35303), you can access it using the `ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.GenerateCode` function, once the ILSpy assemblies have been referenced in your project.